# How to copy data from 3rd party DB without side effects

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers

I need to change our website to show real-time data from 3rd party software (using SQL-Server 2008r2) and I was wondering can anyone advice me in what is the best way to do this.

**So to give you a better idea:**

We have a webpage that uses derived data from our 3rd party systems. Some parts of the derived data take 24 hr to update on our databases because they are timed Agent jobs.

Now I have a request to change the functionality to RT, where every time a change or new data is implemented on 3rd party software/DB it should appear on the website.

I have access to the 3rd party DB:s, but not under the hood of the software.

Views, temp tables, selects directly to the DB are forbidden. The derived data should be in table, so it can be used in further development.

The way I was implementing was to use triggers, how ever in case the 3rd party software holds `@@indentity` commands using insert trigger could result to that the 3rd party software possibly corrupting the data relations on DB.

*So my question is what would be the safest way to implement fetching RT events to 3rd party database?*

Sorry for the long post and thanks for your help!

Comment: WAIT would be nice as it would give time for 3rd party operations to be completed, but I have read that it should not be used with triggers as it takes up too much resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would SQL Track changes help?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx

Also, you can READ from a read-only replica (like a mirror)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213002.aspx

Basically find out what has changed from Track Changes but do the Heavy lifting on the replica so you don't affect performance .

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you. At first glance Track Changes is exactly what I need. Thanks again

Comment: Your welcome, it can get quite technical thought, good luck!!